# want the result of all employee even though he has not done any activity on particular day

Tags: mysql

I have four tables;

- `employee_details` with the columns `emp_code` and `emp_name`
- `actual_all_details` with the columns `emp_code`, `date`, `activity_id`, `card_id`, and `quantity`
- `activities` with the columns `activity_id` (primary key) and `activity`
- `cards` with the columns card `card_id` (primary key) and `card_type`

**activities**:

```
activity_id   activity
    1         Tape laying
    2         Embossing
    3         Courier Packing
    4         Thermal
```

**cards**

```
card_id   card_type
    1     Barcoding
    2     Big Ribbon
    3     Biman All
```

**employee_details**

```
emp_code    emp_name
    1       shraddha
    2       mayuri
    3       kishori
```

**actual_all_detalis table:**

```
emp_code  date         activity_id   card_id   quantity
    1     2015-12-19       1             2         266
    2     2015-12-19       1             3         300
    3     2015-12-19       3             2         400
```

Now I would like my query to return all `emp_code` with their activity even though it has not be done by employee on particular day and it should also return the activity related to card type.
As an example, the result should return the quantity as `0` if `emp_code` 2 has not done any activity on that particular day, e.g.

```
emp_code      date        activity     card_type      quantity   
    2         2015-12-19  Embossing    Barcoding          0
```

Comment: You have a table called `actual_alldetails` and another table called `actual_all_detalis table`? Really?

Comment: its actual_alldetails table name.actual_all_details table name has by  mistakenly done.

Comment: There is an edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT emp_code, date, activity_id, card_id, quantity FROM
 employee_details LEFT JOIN 
 (cards INNER JOIN actual_all_detalis ON cards.card_id = actual_all_detalis.card_id)
    ON actual_all_detalis.emp_code = employee_details.emp_code
WHERE DATEDIFF(date, '2015-12-19') = 0
```